# MSteams outgoing webhook could not communicate to python https endpoint

Tags: python

`I try to create an outgoing webhook from MSteam to send message to a https endpoint running using python flask. I could send message from postman/curl. but msteam throws error "Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request"

1. Python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import hmac, hashlib, base64, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':


        # Reply
        data = request.get_json()
        channel = data['channelId']
        message_type = data['type']
        sender = data['from']['name']
        message_format = data['textFormat']
        message = data['text']

        # Authenticate

        security_token = b"1PmR9wjAFJP8U+BZiZKL6Y8hwGywVZN79riLSd8xfHE="
        request_data = request.get_data()
        digest = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(security_token), msg=request_data, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
        signature = base64.b64encode(digest).decode()

        # TODO: verify that HMAC header == signature

        return jsonify({
            'type' : 'message',
            'text' : 'auth header:'})

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return "Hello World"


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8100, ssl_context=('/usr/local/oracle/jey/xxxxx.crt', '/usr/local/oracle/jey/xxxx.key'))
```

2.Service running and able to ping from https & postmane

-sh-4.4$ python3 f11.py

- Running on https://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: xxx-xxx-xxx
  xx.xxx.x.x - - [03/Apr/2023 20:52:24] "GET /webhook HTTP/1.1" 405 -

^C-sh-4.4$ python3 f11.py

- Running on https://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: xxx-xxx-xxx
  Data received from Webhook is:  {'type': 'message', 'text': 'hello'}
  xx.xx.xx.xx - - [03/Apr/2023 20:55:37] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 -

3. but from msteam throw error "Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request"
   @outgoing_webhook message

I am trying to create outgoing webhook to send message to python https endpoint.`